# Why there is only one data in the List<String>?

Tags: android, arraylist

I used cursor for database selecting and want to put all the data inside a List, then return to the mainactivity. But after debugging, I found that there is only the first data inside the return value.

```
public List<String> select1 (String ReservedState, String mycity, String mystreet, String mypostcode){
    ReservedState="Free";
    SQLiteDatabase Database1=dbHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DbHelper1.KEY_ID1,DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE, DbHelper1.KEY_GEOGRAPHICALLOCATION,DbHelper1.KEY_CITY,DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE,DbHelper1.KEY_STREET};
    Cursor cursor=Database1.query(DbHelper1.TABLE_NAME_1,columns, DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE+"='"+ReservedState+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_CITY+"='"+mycity+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE+"='"+mypostcode+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_STREET+"='"+mystreet+"'",null,null,null,null);
    //StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    List<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper1.KEY_ID1);
        String id=cursor.getString(index1);
        al.add(id);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return al;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> select1 (String ReservedState, String mycity, String mystreet, String mypostcode){
        ReservedState="Free";
        SQLiteDatabase Database1=dbHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={DbHelper1.KEY_ID1,DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE, DbHelper1.KEY_GEOGRAPHICALLOCATION,DbHelper1.KEY_CITY,DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE,DbHelper1.KEY_STREET};
        Cursor cursor=Database1.query(DbHelper1.TABLE_NAME_1,columns, DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE+"='"+ReservedState+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_CITY+"='"+mycity+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE+"='"+mypostcode+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_STREET+"='"+mystreet+"'",null,null,null,null);
        Log.e("Cursor",""+cursor.getCount());
        //StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        do{
            int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper1.KEY_ID1);
            String id=cursor.getString(index1);
            list.add(id);
          }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        return al;
    }
```

Try this. Hope this will help.

Comment: Still only one result...T_T

Comment: are you sure table contains more than one rows?

Comment: @dacandou check the database values. which satisfy the condition.

Comment: The table contains three rows which are the same

Comment: For the Log.e, the text is 0, is means I can only select the first row, right? Then if so, what should I do to improve?

Comment: i think the problem is with your condition given in query.

Comment: The condition is check four columns of the table and find id which meets all these four requirements.

Comment: Just try to get All datas from table without condition? Still only 1?

Comment: I tried rawQuery with "SELECT * FROM"+DbHelper1.TABLE_NAME_1,null. still only one.

Comment: Are u sure it has more than 1 data?

Comment: When I opened the database under asset folder and type "SELECT rowid, * FROM "ReservedStatus";", I can see three rows.

Comment: I knwo what went wrong. Everytime I want to insert data, I have to create a new table and then put it under asset. Last time, I used the same table, so even through I could see three rows, it is still one row with processing.